# Solving the equation $X^a \bmod b = N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does this equation has a unique solution? Is it solvable?

$$X^a \bmod b = N$$

where

`X` is unknown

`a`, `b`, and `N` are all known

Comment: Just work some examples; that should clarify the situation for you.

Comment: Is $\gcd(N,b)=1$?

Comment: Usually the solution is not unique and may not exist at all. A lot depends on whether $N$ is coprime to $b$ and also about whether $a$ is coprime to $\phi(b)$.

Comment: But I recommend that you take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). The present version is either too broad, or missing context - I can't decide which is more pressing. Also, we have **several** closely related threads dedicated to special cases. Did you search the site

Comment: The special cases $a=2$ and $b$ an odd prime are treated by the topic of *quadratic residues* in classical number theory.  If you are studying number theory, see Fermat's little theorem and Euler's generalization of that.  In any case please add context:  why does the problem interest you?

Comment: @hardmath I'm trying to resolve a cryptographic challenge (neither school or work related) and I got faced with that equation. I could not figure out whether it's even solvable or not. Considering this is getting me this deep in math theory, I suppose it's fair to say I've taken a wrong approach to my challenge and should try to solve it another way. Thanks a mil all for your help!

Comment: Pauline, telling us about the underlying cryptographic challenge would have been exactly the kind of context this question needs. Also, exactly because the difficulties in this type of a question underlie certain crypto-applications, it would have shaped the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm responding to the Comment by the OP, responding to my request for context.  It seems that there is a real context for the Question that has yet to be shared, so I'm marking this as a Community Wiki Answer and hoping that it helps the OP to better understand what kind of context will be useful to willing Readers.

In a "cryptographic challenge" I would expect that you know something important about the "known" values of $a,b,N$.  Whether the equation is solvable (and whether such solutions are unique) is dependent on their specific values, as you will see from doing a few examples.

A mathematical way of writing the equation (in contrast with the "programmer way" of writing it in the body of the Question) is:

$$ x^a \equiv N \bmod b $$

A general approach to solving such equations is the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm):

> "Several important algorithms in public-key cryptography base their security on the assumption that the discrete logarithm problem over carefully chosen groups has no efficient solution."

But this does not save us from needing to know what kind of values $a,b,N$ are.

Is $b$ a prime?  Is $N$ coprime to $b$, or perhaps is $N$ zero?  The Question as currently stated does not actually tell us that these are (positive?) integer values.

Information of this kind is critical to determining whether the equation necessarily has a solution, and whether such a solution will be unique.